# "Error in parse(text = bodyStr2) : <text>:1:23: unexpected 'if' 1: { numParm <- 4 if ^"

Tags: r, string, parsing, syntax-error

I'm trying to adjust my data on tree growth to Gompertz equation. Can you help me solve this error?

Once I fixed which data is 'x' and which is 'y', the line with the error is this one:

```
ajuste <- drm(Y ~ X, data = Gomp_D1, fct = G.4, start = c(Asym = max(Gomp_D1$Y), b = 1, c = 1))
```

And the error is:

```
Error in parse(text = bodyStr2) : <text>:1:23: unexpected 'if'
1: {     numParm <- 4    if
                          ^
```

I understand that there is a wrong hyphen or a number at the beginning of a string but cannot detect it.
Thanks!

I am expecting to get a Gompertz (sigmoid) curve with my data adjusted to that curve. Then, I'll calculate how accurate the model is to predict/model tree growth.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've shown that would clearly indicate where the issue is. Checking the [`drm` cran-repo](https://github.com/cran/drm) (since it was archived 5 years ago, and the `DESCRIPTION` url returns 404), there is no reference to `numParm` or `bodyStr2` in that package, suggesting the issue is elsewhere. If those variables look familiar to you, please include context on how/where they are defined/used.

Comment: You should provide (example) data with this question; even if it's just dummy data, or the first couple of rows of the dataframe you are using. It is impossible to figure out what is going wrong here, as the error message does not seem to be related to the function. So either there is something going on with the data (so please add it), or there is other code that is not being shown here that is causing this error. To get good quality answers, please provide the most complete information you can in the question.